# HttpURLConnection: set Byte-range request after connected

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

So I used the setRequestProperty to send a Byte-Range request to a URL. But the problem is I want to get the size first using getContentLength. However, the compiler complains that I was already connected to that URl after asking for the length, I can no longer set the byte-range. Is there anyway to do this in this particular order w/o it throwing an error? I tried to go: 
getContentLength() -> connection.disconnect() -> setRequestProperty() ->connection.connect(). But that didn't work either. After I disconnected it and connect again, it didn't receive any data at all.

Answer (score 0):

An HttpURLConnection is used to make a **single** request to the server and can not be reused for a subsequent request.  And since getContentLength() returns the length of the **response**, by the time it returns the request has already been sent, which is why you can no longer add headers to the request afterwards.

You can use two HttpURLConnections -- the first one to request the length of the document, and the second one (in which you set the Range header based on the length you got from the first request) to get the actual document range you're interested in.